# Как заставить общаться клиент на localhost с сервером на localhost

Tags: node.js, angular2, angular4

Поднимаю элементарный сервер на ноде на локалхосте на порте 3030.
Запускаю dev сервер ангуляр на локалхосте на порте 4200

Мне нужно делать запросы из ангуляр приложения к серверу. 
Но я получаю ошибку
Failed to load http://localhost:3030/api/data: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Создаю файл proxy.conf.json со следующим содержимым:

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:3030",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```

Запускаю клиент командой ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json
Но это не помогает. Ошибка прежняя.
Как быть?

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался. Чтобы убрать ошибку, нужно в ajax запросе вместо абсолютного адреса http://localhost:3030/api/data использовать относительный /api/data